# User choose shipping method by product in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I have an online store which was built with WooCommerce.

I want to offer to the users the possibility of chose, item by item in the shopping cart, what shipping method they want, showing them in a combo/radio the options with the carrier, cost and delivery dates, for every product they've added.

I've developed a plugin with does complex calculations and offers several shipping options, but works just for the entire order, not by item.

I've searched a lot for a plugin or another solution for this case, and haven't succeed.

Is there possible ways to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: The answer is always yes (because nothing is impossible depending on your skills and the time to spend doing it)… But Stack OverFlow is code oriented and you should ask something small (not broad), defined and related to a peace of code included in your question. For now your question is just too vague (unclear) and can tend to give answer based on opinions.

Comment: Yes, I know. But, any piece of code that I may put here wouldn't help anyone to understand the problem. I don't think it's really a code related question, It's more a conceptual question, for which I'm searching for orientation.